Flask Session Not Retaining State Parameter During Google OAuth2 Authentication
I'm building a Flask application that integrates with Google Drive using OAuth2 for authentication. The flow works fine initially, but I'm encountering an issue where the state parameter is missing from the session when redirected back from Google. This results in an error message: { "text": "State parameter missing in session. Please try authenticating again." }.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
`from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, session, jsonify
from flask_session import Session
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import os
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'

# Configure server-side session
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = False
app.config['SESSION_USE_SIGNER'] = True
app.config['SESSION_FILE_DIR'] = './.flask_session/'
app.config['SESSION_FILE_THRESHOLD'] = 100
Session(app)

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    event = request.json
    user_message = event['message']['text'].strip().lower()

    if user_message == 'start':
        return start_authentication(event)
    if 'drive.google.com' in user_message:
        link = user_message
        return validate_drive_link(event, link)

    return jsonify({"text": "Please provide a valid Google Drive link or type 'start' to begin."})

def start_authentication(event):
    flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
        scopes=SCOPES,
        redirect_uri=url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
    )
    auth_url, state = flow.authorization_url()
    session['state'] = state  # Store the state in session

    return jsonify({"text": f"Please authorize the bot to access your Google Drive: {auth_url}"})

@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    try:
        state = session['state']  # Retrieve the state from session
    except KeyError:
        return jsonify({"text": "State parameter missing in session. Please try authenticating again."})

    flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
        scopes=SCOPES,
        state=state,
        redirect_uri=url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
    )
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=request.url)

    credentials = flow.credentials
    session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

    return jsonify({"text": "Authentication successful. Please provide your Google Drive link."})

# Additional helper functions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)`

The problem occurs during the callback, where the state parameter seems to be missing from the session. I've checked that the session data is being set correctly before the redirection.
Questions:

What could be causing the state parameter to be missing from the session during the OAuth2 callback?
How can I ensure that the state parameter persists in the session across the OAuth2 flow?

I've ensured that the session is properly configured to use the filesystem, but the issue persists. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

What I Tried:

Storing the state parameter in the session:
session['state'] = state

This is done right after generating the authorization URL in the start_authentication function.

Retrieving the state parameter from the session:
state = session['state']

This is done in the oauth2callback function to ensure the state parameter matches the one sent to Google.


What I Expected:
I expected the state parameter to be stored in the session during the initial authentication step, and then be available in the session when Google redirects back to my application after the user grants permission. This would allow me to complete the OAuth2 flow and exchange the authorization code for tokens.
What Actually Happened:
When redirected back from Google, the session does not contain the state parameter, resulting in the following error message:
{ "text": "State parameter missing in session. Please try authenticating again." }

Questions:

What could be causing the state parameter to be missing from the session during the OAuth2 callback?
How can I ensure that the state parameter persists in the session across the OAuth2 flow?

I've ensured that the session is properly configured to use the filesystem, but the issue persists. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
